# How does React implement useEffect and useLayoutEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, event-handling

I understand the difference between `useEffect` and `useLayoutEffect` but I am curious how it is implemented.

I created this [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-effect-ordering-7r3sp?file=/src/index.js) which shows the order that things occur:

`Log.js`:

```js
export default function Log(count, ref) {
  console.log(`Synchronous ${count}: Ran after ${ref.current}`);
  queueMicrotask(() =>
    console.log(`Microtask ${count}: Ran after ${ref.current}`)
  );
  setImmediate(() => console.log(`Task ${count}: Ran after ${ref.current}`));
}
```

`App.scala`:

```js
import { forwardRef, useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useState } from "react";

import Log from "./Log";

const App = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const [, setCount] = useState(0);
  ref.current = "render";
  Log(2, ref);
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    ref.current = "useLayoutEffect";
  });
  Log(3, ref);
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = "useEffect";
  });
  Log(4, ref);
  return (
    <button
      onClick={() => {
        console.log("Click");
        setCount((x) => x + 1);
      }}
    >
      Click
    </button>
  );
});

export default App;
```

`index.js`:

```js
import React, { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import App from "./App";
import Log from "./Log";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");

const ref = React.createRef();
ref.current = "start";

Log(1, ref);

ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App ref={ref} />
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);

Log(5, ref);
```

After running the App and clicking the button the console shows:

```
Synchronous 1: Ran after start 
Synchronous 2: Ran after render 
Synchronous 3: Ran after render 
Synchronous 4: Ran after render 
Synchronous 5: Ran after useLayoutEffect 
Microtask 1: Ran after useLayoutEffect 
Microtask 2: Ran after useLayoutEffect 
Microtask 3: Ran after useLayoutEffect 
Microtask 4: Ran after useLayoutEffect 
Microtask 2: Ran after useLayoutEffect 
Microtask 3: Ran after useLayoutEffect 
Microtask 4: Ran after useLayoutEffect 
Microtask 5: Ran after useLayoutEffect 
Task 1: Ran after useLayoutEffect 
Task 2: Ran after useLayoutEffect 
Task 3: Ran after useLayoutEffect 
Task 4: Ran after useLayoutEffect 
Task 2: Ran after useLayoutEffect 
Task 3: Ran after useLayoutEffect 
Task 4: Ran after useLayoutEffect 
Task 5: Ran after useEffect 
Click 
Synchronous 2: Ran after render 
Synchronous 3: Ran after render 
Synchronous 4: Ran after render 
Microtask 2: Ran after useLayoutEffect 
Microtask 3: Ran after useLayoutEffect 
Microtask 4: Ran after useLayoutEffect 
Microtask 2: Ran after useLayoutEffect 
Microtask 3: Ran after useLayoutEffect 
Microtask 4: Ran after useLayoutEffect 
Task 2: Ran after useEffect 
Task 3: Ran after useEffect 
Task 4: Ran after useEffect 
Task 2: Ran after useEffect 
Task 3: Ran after useEffect 
Task 4: Ran after useEffect
```

The first thing that I noticed was:

```
Synchronous 5: Ran after useLayoutEffect
```

This shows that `useLayoutEffect` is firing before microtasks that have been scheduled before it. This means that it is not implemented as a microtask but must be some internal task queue (not really that surprising).

The next thing was:

```
Task 4: Ran after useLayoutEffect
```

Since `useEffect` yields to the browser to render and run other tasks I was expecting it to be implemented as a task and so be scheduled between task 3 and 4 in the next event loop iteration.

The only explanation that I can come up with as to why it occurs between task 4 and 5 is that React is creating a task but instead of scheduling it when the hook is called it queues it internally and then after render has completed it creates a task to execute that effect queue.

The next render after clicking the button shows something different:

```
Task 2: Ran after useEffect 
Task 3: Ran after useEffect 
Task 4: Ran after useEffect
```

Here it seems to have preemptively scheduled the task to process effects before the hooks were actually called.

Can anyone shed light on how it actually works?

---

**Bonus Question**

Strict mode is causing the component to render twice each time which is why we see duplicate entries for:

```
Microtask 2: Ran after useLayoutEffect 
Microtask 3: Ran after useLayoutEffect 
Microtask 4: Ran after useLayoutEffect
```

Why aren't there duplicate entries for these?

```
Synchronous 2: Ran after render 
Synchronous 3: Ran after render 
Synchronous 4: Ran after render
```